# Possible issues and best practices for this piece of code

Tags: c#

```
public class NANDFunction : FunctionInfo
{
    public override string Name { get { return "NAND"; } }
    public override int MinArgs { get { return 2; } }
    public override int MaxArgs { get { return 2; } }

    public override object Evaluate(object[] args)
    {
        bool arg0 = CalcConvert.ToBool(args[0]);
        bool arg1 = CalcConvert.ToBool(args[1]);
        return ((arg0 != arg1) || (!arg0 && !arg1));
    }
}
```

What do you think of this code?

Comment: Is FunctionInfo a class you've created?  If so, what does it look like?

Comment: no, it is from a third party control , a spread sheet control..

Comment: static analysis tell me I can remove the last "!arg1" because it is always true...I don' get it why it says that either.

Comment: Because if arg0 = true and arg1 = false then the left part of the or passes and the statement exists. Therefore if you get to the right part of the check, if arg0 is false the right part fails there, if it is true, it failed in the left side, so you will never hit the !arg1 check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to add some additional validation around how many arguments you're expecting (since you know via `MinArgs` and `MaxArgs`). You can also eliminate having to create an object array explicitly in the caller by using the `params` keyword (make sure you do it in the declaration in `FunctionInfo` as well). Lastly, if this class is intended to be non-inheritable (unlike `FunctionInfo`), mark it as `sealed`:

```
public sealed class NANDFunction : FunctionInfo
{
    public override string Name { get { return "NAND"; } }
    public override int MinArgs { get { return 2; } }
    public override int MaxArgs { get { return 2; } }

    public override object Evaluate(params object[] args)
    {
        if ((args.Length < this.MinArgs) || (args.Length > this.MaxArgs))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("An insufficient number of arguments were passed.");
        }

        bool arg0 = CalcConvert.ToBool(args[0]);
        bool arg1 = CalcConvert.ToBool(args[1]);
        return (arg0 != arg1) || (!arg0 && !arg1);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, the argument validation (the `if` block with the `throw`) might be better handled in the `FunctionInfo` superclass' implementation of `Evaluate` and be replaced in the subclass with a call to `base.Evaluate(args);`.

Comment: Sharing the common validation is a good idea, but I don't like calling the base implementation for that. For one, you're calling a method that returns something and you'll always ignore that. I think separating this into `public Evaluate` and `protected abstract EvaluateNoValidation` (or some better name) would be better.